# cwRsync adding "." to filename and erroring "Operation not permitted"

Tags: batch-file, cwrsync

I'm trying to use cwRsync, version 3.2.3  protocol version 31, on a fully patched Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit machine to copy files to a FreeNAS running FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p14. The command I'm using is:
`rsync -avhe "./ssh -i C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\rsync\cwRsync\6v2.1\bin\Andrew_Laptop" --exclude 'Thumbs.db' --delete /cygdrive/C/Users/Andrew/Documents andrew@192.168.1.240:/mnt/FreeNAS_1/backup/Andrew/Laptop/Documents`
and it works for most of the the files, about 12,000. The command is called from a batch file, output 2>&1 to an activity log file. On checking the activity log there are a lot of messages thus:

`rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/FreeNAS_1/backup/Andrew/Laptop/Documents/Documents .cc_20171013_092617.reg.LvUTpY" failed: Operation not permitted (1)`

about 6,000 of these.
It turns out that all the files that have failed have a full stop "." prepended to the front of the filename in the failure message and random numbers appended after, as per above `".cc_20171013_092617.reg.LvUTpY"`. The Source filename is `"cc_20171013_092617.reg"`. The files also do not exist in the Destination folder of the NAS.
Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm also having this problem rn with rsync and my NAS over FTP. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember determining that these were temporary files, and so legitimate, and shouldn’t be copied. I think.

As you can see, I got no response from the post I made. Nor did I get any help from https://www.itefix.net/ who provide cwRsync.

In the end I gave up and used XXCOPY, http://www.xxcopy.com/. It runs from a Command Line, doesn’t require a Windows package installation of 20Tb to work. (The whole XXCOPY directory is only 2.5Mb!).

My whole need for using these was to ensure that I got a REAL Backup of my data; Windoze doesn’t verify that the data it thinks it has copied, has actually happened. You need to use third party products to do this.

(I wasn’t impressed when I found this out!).

Although XXCOPY hasn’t been supported for some time, it did what it said it would do. First time. To prove it I it ran the windows fc command on all the files I’d used XXCOPY to copy. A prudent exercise on ANY data you back up. It took some time but confirmed XXCOPY was working.